# I can't upload images in CKEditor

Tags: media, 8

With Drupal 8 I'm having issues uploading images in a node.

I select an image in the upload dialog box and add it, yet when I go to view the page the image is not there? Directory permissions for image uploads are set to read/write.

When I inspect the source, I don't even see an image path.

My upload dialog box looks pretty crappy too.

> [image: upload dialog box]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure: Is `<img>` allowed for the input format you select? Did you save the node?

Comment: I believe so, this is just the vanilla Drupal 8 install, I've made no configuration changes

Comment: Resolved with update to Drupal 8.0.1

Comment: May I ask which browser this is? Or did you perhaps customize the default admin theme (called 'Seven')? This is *not* what it looks like out of the box on any browser I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with update to Drupal 8.0.1